# AltBeacon library - UUID returning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am trying to create an Android app thats detect a rasperry pi by using the AltBeacon library by davidgyoung. So far I am able to get most data including distance, although the only things that I really need are dBms and the UUID of the device. Inside the rangeNotifier() function I pretty much print every piece of data to see if the UUID might come out somewhere that matches the one of the device but the only thing that resembles a UUID is given to me as "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" and is found by using the getIdentifier method. Any ideas why I can't see the actual UUID of the device? Thanks!!

Comment: How do you know what the "actual uuid of the device" is?  Are you sure it is not advertising  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?

Comment: A co-worker used his iPhone and downloaded a beacon detector app which showed the UUID as well as other info. It did showed a certain UUID. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S8 as well as an LG phone and downloaded a bunch of beacon detector apps. All of them gave 0000s as UUID so I am thinking it might be an Android issue. In any case I think I can use the bluetooth address as an identifier instead. Thanks for responding and I really appreciate the library that you developed!

Answer (score 0):

If multiple Android apps say the ProximityUUID is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, then they are probably right.

The reason iOS apps probably won't detect 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is because unlike Android,  **iOS can only detect a beacon's UUID if it is pre-configured** into the app (yeah, that's a chicken and egg problem I know!) and your UUID is probably not configured into those iOS apps.  So it may be showing the ProximityUUID of a different beacon in the vicinity.

Also, don't confuse the Bluetooth GATT Service UUID with the iBeacon Proximity UUID. Even though these look superficially similar -- they are completely different identifiers  If you are using a more general Bluetooth scanning app on iOS (and not a beacon scanning app) this may be what iOS is seeing.

Comment: We knew it was detecting the same rasperry pi was because we also noticed both the Android and iPhone phones signaled the same bluetooth address coming out of the pi, essentially the only thing that differed was the UUID, all else including Tx were the same.

Comment: Something isn't quite right there... because iOS devices don't let you read the bluetooth MAC address.  The operating system blocks access, wheres Android does not.